# How can I update valor_total for each fatura_id using the sum above

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, sql-update

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ATUALIZARVALORTOTAL (ANO NUMBER, MES NUMBER) as;  
BEGIN
    UPDATE FATURA
        SET VALOR_TOTAL = (SELECT SUM(DETALHE_FATURA.VALOR) 
                            FROM DETALHE_FATURA, FATURA
                            WHERE DETALHE_FATURA.ID_FATURA = FATURA.ID_FATURA AND 
                            EXTRACT (YEAR FROM FATURA.DATA_EMISSAO) = ANO AND 
                            EXTRACT (MONTH FROM FATURA.DATA_EMISSAO) = MES
                            GROUP BY DETALHE_FATURA.ID_FATURA, DETALHE_FATURA.ID_FATURA)
                            ;           
END;
```

-- TEST

```
BEGIN
    ATUALIZARVALORTOTAL(2019, 10);
END;
```

Comment: I think using group by clause is giving you multiple records and causing your update failure. What is the exact error you are getting. Sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MERGE` statement for it as follows:

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ATUALIZARVALORTOTAL (
>     ANO NUMBER,
>     MES NUMBER
> ) AS
> BEGIN
>     MERGE INTO FATURA TRG USING (
>                                     SELECT
>                                         DETALHE_FATURA.ID_FATURA,
>                                         SUM(DETALHE_FATURA.VALOR) AS VALOR
>                                     FROM
>                                         DETALHE_FATURA
>                                         JOIN FATURA 
>                                         ON ( DETALHE_FATURA.ID_FATURA = FATURA.ID_FATURA )
>                                     WHERE
>                                         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FATURA.DATA_EMISSAO) = ANO
>                                         AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM FATURA.DATA_EMISSAO) = MES
>                                     GROUP BY
>                                         DETALHE_FATURA.ID_FATURA
>                                 )
>     SRC ON ( TRG.ID_FATURA = SRC.ID_FATURA )
>     WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TRG.VALOR_TOTAL = SRC.VALOR;
>
> END;
> ```

Also, try to use **standard ANSI joins**.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have the error message, but in any case I don't think this procedure will do what you want.  You need a where clause for the update or it will update every row in the table.

```
UPDATE FATURA
        SET VALOR_TOTAL = (SELECT SUM(DETALHE_FATURA.VALOR) 
                            FROM DETALHE_FATURA, FATURA
                            WHERE DETALHE_FATURA.ID_FATURA = FATURA.ID_FATURA AND 
                            EXTRACT (YEAR FROM FATURA.DATA_EMISSAO) = ANO AND 
                            EXTRACT (MONTH FROM FATURA.DATA_EMISSAO) = MES
                            GROUP BY DETALHE_FATURA.ID_FATURA)                           
where EXTRACT( YEAR FROM FATURA.DATA_EMISSAO) = ANO and
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM FATURA.DATA_EMISSAO) = MES;
```